# Sending Mails in Serial Order using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c

When ever the user Clicks on a picture the image should be sent to his mail.I want this to happen in background so I am using SKPSMTPMessage. I am getting an Error if the user clicks a picture before the previous one is sent/Uploaded.I thought I will use GCD to serialise this but I am not able to solve it.

```
- (IBAction)snapStillImage:(id)sender
{

        //code after taking the picture
            if([uploadMethod isEqualToString:@"Mail"]){
                time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
                NSString *timestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",unixTime];
                NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
                [jpgData writeToFile:[self documentsPathForFileName:timestamp] atomically:YES];
                [self.imagesArray addObject:timestamp];
                [self sendMail];

}


-(void)sendMail{
dispatch_queue_t myFifoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxxx.uploadpictures",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
if(!self.imagesArray.count == 0){
    for(NSString *str in self.imagesArray){
        dispatch_async(myFifoQueue,^{
            [self sendMailWith:str];
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try operation queue for it. create multiple operation & schedule then in execution order. check this [nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. As Andrey points out, you want to create only one queue, rather than creating a new queue every time.
2. Given that `SKPSMTPMessage` operates asynchronously, if you want these to run sequentially, you need to refactor this code so that the next request won't start until the prior, asynchronous request, is done. The typical solution for this is to:

   - Use operation queues (`NSOperationQueue`).
   - Wrap your asynchronous send request in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass. You'd set up your `NSOperation` to be the `delegate` for the `SKPSMTPMessage` object, and in the `messageSent` and `messageFailed` methods, you would complete the operation (post the necessary `isFinished` and `isExecuting` notifications).

     See the *Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution* section of the [Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1) chapter of the *Concurrency Programming Guide* for more information.
   - Make sure your configure your queue or operations so they'll be sent sequentially (e.g. set the operation queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 to make it a serial queue).

---

To illustrate, you'd define an operation queue:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *mailQueue;
```

You'd configure it once:

```
self.mailQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.mailQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

And you'd then add mail requests to that queue:

```
[self.mailQueue addOperation:[[SendEmailOperation alloc] initWithTo:@"rob@example.com"
                                                            subject:@"title"
                                                               body:@"body"
                                                               path:pathToImage]];
```

So, the interesting question is what this `SendMailOperation` might look like:

```
//  SendEmailOperation.h

#import "ConcurrentOperation.h"

@interface SendEmailOperation : ConcurrentOperation

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *to;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *body;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *path;

- (instancetype)initWithTo:(NSString *)to subject:(NSString *)subject body:(NSString *)body path:(NSString *)path;

@end
```

and

```
//  SendEmailOperation.m

#import "SendEmailOperation.h"
#import "SKPSMTPMessage.h"

@interface SendEmailOperation () <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate>

@end

@implementation SendEmailOperation

- (instancetype)initWithTo:(NSString *)to subject:(NSString *)subject body:(NSString *)body path:(NSString *)path
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.to = to;
        self.subject = subject;
        self.body = body;
        self.path = path;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    SKPSMTPMessage *message = [self createMessage]; // configure your message like you are now
    message.delegate = self;
    [message send];
}

- (SKPSMTPMessage *)createMessage
{
    SKPSMTPMessage *message = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

    // configure this message like you are now, picking up the various class properties
    // (e.g. to, subject, body, etc.).

    return message;
}

#pragma mark - SKPSMTPMessageDelegate

-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message
{
    [self completeOperation];
}

-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);

    [self completeOperation];
}

@end
```

And, finally, the guts of the concurrent operation subclass is squirreled away in this `ConcurrentOperation` class. Once you start using concurrent operations, you'll find yourself using this pattern a lot, so this class saves you from having to constantly re-implement concurrent operation subclass stuff:

```
//  ConcurrentOperation.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ConcurrentOperation : NSOperation

- (void)completeOperation;

@end
```

and

```
//  ConcurrentOperation.m

#import "ConcurrentOperation.h"

@interface ConcurrentOperation ()

@property (nonatomic, getter = isFinished, readwrite)  BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isExecuting, readwrite) BOOL executing;

@end

@implementation ConcurrentOperation

@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _finished  = NO;
        _executing = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    [self main];
}

- (void)completeOperation
{
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished  = YES;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation methods

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    if (_executing != executing) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        _executing = executing;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    if (_finished != finished) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _finished = finished;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    }
}

@end
```

I know this looks like a lot, but once you have `ConcurrentOperation` (or something like it) in your tool belt, you'll find that creating concurrent operations is really easy, and is incredibly useful whenever you want to perform a series of asynchronous tasks sequentially (or concurrently with some special dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for all the effort Rob..!!

Answer (score 3):

The code, as written now, creates a new queue every time the `sendMail` method is called, and submits a block on this new queue, thus no serial execution.

To fix it you can make `myFifoQueue` an instance variable (e.g. create it in `init` method), or make it static, e.g.:

```
-(void)sendMail {
    dispatch_queue_t myFifoQueue;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        myFifoQueue = dispatch_queue_create(...);
    }

    if(!self.imagesArray.count == 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```